# Access session attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I need some help understanding how to do what I suppose it should be an easy thing.

In my controller I am converting a PDF into several images, and I can easily get page number being dealt with and total number of pages that needs to be doing. I am putting both in the session with:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("currentPageNumber", currentPageNumber);
request.getSession().setAttribute("totalPagesNumber", totalPagesNumber);
```

On the view I'd like to show a progress bar knowing these values, doing something like CeilingOf((currentPageNumber/totalPagesNumber)*100) but I don't know how to continuously get those updated values.

If I use:

```
'<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("currentPageNumber")%>'
```

this will be resolved loading the page (before the session is even being updated with the attributes) and both show up null.

What do I need to do to access these values on the view? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If you're using node.js, you should tag this question node.js. If you're using the request library for node.js, you should tag it with request. As for your actual question, displaying a progress bar on the client for something happening on the server is waaaay more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that directly. Because JavaScript is executed on the client side (browser), and the session data on the server.

Some ways to use session attribute variables in JavaScript:

- a hidden input field storing the variable as its value and reading it through the DOM API
- an HTML5 data attribute which you can read through the DOM
- storing it as a cookie and accessing it through JavaScript
- injecting it directly in the JS code, if you have it inline

In JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalPagesNumber" value="${sessionScope.totalPagesNumber} />
```

Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), len = inputs.length, i, totalPagesNumber;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name == "totalPagesNumber") {
        totalPagesNumber = inputs[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here i am looping all the input hidden fields so that you can get all the values in one loop.

Answer (score -1):

`${currentPageNumber}`
will access the attribute

Comment: Please provide more context about where to include this and how it is used.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 